# Как убрать повторение кода обработчиков событий элементов управления?

Tags: c#, winforms, события, lambda

Доброго времени суток.

Прошу помощи в усмирении моего внутреннего перфекциониста. Негодует он от того, что я дублирую код. Сейчас поясню.

На форме я динамически создаю в функции три элемента управления: `Panel`, `PictureBox` и `Label`. Последние два относятся к только что созданному первому элементу управления как дочерние.

```
private void ConstructUser(int uidx, string name, string avatar_path);
```

По нажатию на любой из этих элементов управления я желаю выполнить некоторый код, который использует локальные переменные `uidx` и `name`. Я не смог придумать никакой иной реализации, кроме как использование лямбда обработчиков событий:

```
Panel ctrl = new Panel();
// ...
ctrl.MouseClick += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ShowUserInfo(uidx, name); // ShowUserInfo - еще одна функция формы.
    }
};
```

В этом то и проблема. Событие происходит только когда я нажимаю на панель `ctrl` (менее 5% от общего покрытия нажимаемой зоны; 95% занимают дочерние элементы управления).

- Я не могу сказать дочерним элементам управления панели `ctrl`, что желаю получать их события `MouseClick` в обработчике `MouseClick` элемента `ctrl`.
- Я не могу использовать функцию формы как обработчик так как мне нужен доступ к локальным переменным `uidx` и `name`, существующим только в контексте функции-создателе `ConstructUser`.
- Я не могу панели `ctrl` дописать свои дополнительные данные, которые содержали бы локальные переменные `uidx` и `name`, чтобы использовать функцию формы. Писать обертку класса `Panel` считаю несуразным. Уверен, сам `Panel` имеет такие возможности, но я о них и близко не в курсе.
- Я не могу создать лямбда функцию как переменную. Тут уже сказывается малый опыт на c#. Лямбда функциям как переменным обязательно необходимо возвращаемое значение. Нет тут его.

В итоге всего мне пришлось дублировать код обработчика для всех создаваемых элементов управления.

```
ctrl.MouseClick += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ShowUserInfo(uidx, name);
    }
};
_myPictureBox1.MouseClick += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ShowUserInfo(uidx, name);
    }
};
_myLabel1.MouseClick += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ShowUserInfo(uidx, name);
    }
};
```

Этой сейчас мне не страшно: три строчки кода повторить три раза. А что будет в бедующем? А тогда я буду иметь ваши ответы.

Мне было бы интересно увидеть ответ решения на любой или на каждый из перечисленных пунктов выше. Любой из них решает мою проблему, а чем больше - тем вариативнее станет мой выбор программного решения.

Спасибо за внимание.

### Приложение А

Всего выше хватит для ответа, но приведу код фигурируемых тут функций из главной формы `Form1`. Это на случай, если вы захотите полностью повторить мою ситуацию.

```
private void ShowUserInfo(int uidx, string name)
{
    Form2 _ = new Form2(uidx, name); // Ошибка? Можете просто удалить тело этой функции.
    _.Show();
}

private int offset = 0; // px; c++ like static local variable...
private void ConstructUser(int uidx, string name, string avatar_path)
{
    // CONTROLS:
    int cx_w = SystemInformation.FixedFrameBorderSize.Width * 2 + SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;

    Panel ctrl       = new Panel();
    ctrl.Parent      = panel1; // Ошибка? Обязан быть. Не забудьте свойство AutoScroll = true.
    ctrl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    ctrl.Location    = new Point(0, offset);
    ctrl.Size        = new Size(ctrl.Parent.Width - cx_w, 64);
    ctrl.Font        = ctrl.Parent.Font;
    ctrl.Parent.Controls.Add(ctrl);

    offset += ctrl.Size.Height + 12; // h + padding

    PictureBox avatar  = new PictureBox();
    avatar.Parent      = ctrl;
    avatar.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    avatar.Location    = new Point(0, 0);
    avatar.SizeMode    = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    avatar.Size        = new Size(64, 64);
    avatar.Image       = Image.FromFile(avatar_path);
    avatar.Parent.Controls.Add(avatar);

    Label nm     = new Label();
    nm.Parent    = ctrl;
    nm.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
    nm.Location  = new Point(avatar.Size.Width + 6, 0);
    nm.Size      = new Size(nm.Parent.Width - avatar.Width - 12 - SystemInformation.BorderSize.Width * 2, nm.Parent.Height);
    nm.Font      = nm.Parent.Font;
    nm.Text      = name;
    nm.Parent.Controls.Add(nm);

    // COLORS:
    avatar.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
    ctrl.BackColor   = Color.Coral;
    nm.BackColor     = Color.Silver;

    // EVENTS:
    ctrl.MouseClick += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            ShowUserInfo(uidx, name);
        }
    };
    avatar.MouseClick += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            ShowUserInfo(uidx, name);
        }
    };
    nm.MouseClick += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            ShowUserInfo(uidx, name);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Если вы часто используете какой-то код, и он повторяется, выносите его в отдельные функции.

Comment: @こきん, читайте внимательнее.

Comment: Кхм, у класса Control, есть свойство `Tag`, туда можно положить необходимые данные

Comment: @こきん, Спасибо. Ваш комментарий-ответ очень в тему. Таким образом я могу использовать не  только локальные или lambda функции как обработчики события, но и функции класса формы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант с локальной функцией

```
void myHandler (object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ShowUserInfo(uidx, name);
    }
};

// EVENTS:
ctrl.MouseClick += myHandler;
avatar.MouseClick += myHandler;
nm.MouseClick += myHandler;
```

Вариант с лямбдой

```
var myHandler = new MouseEventHandler((object sender, MouseEventArgs e)=>
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ShowUserInfo(uidx, name);
    }
});

// EVENTS:
ctrl.MouseClick += myHandler;
avatar.MouseClick += myHandler;
nm.MouseClick += myHandler;
```